# Intellij (PyCharm) does not recognize AltGr Shortcuts anymore in Linux

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a German keyboard and I am using my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> for short cuts very heavily.
Now I recently switched to a newer Linux version and all my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> stopped working.
Instead of executing the command attributed to the shortcut the bound character i.e. `ŋ` for <kbd>Alt Gr + G</kbd> was shown.

Doing some research I found some long standing related bug tickets:

- [National keyboard layouts support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165950)
- [AltGr shortcut not working on Ubuntu](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-273945)
- [Alt Gr (German keyboard layout) not working for shortcuts](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88508/Alt-Gr-German-keyboard-layout-not-working-for-shortcuts)
- [Cannot type characters that require AltGr](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209426/Cannot-type-characters-that-require-AltGr)

But none of the settings shown there fixed the shortcuts. So how to fix them?

The output of `xmodmap -pke` and `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` showed no difference between my old Linux (working shortcuts) and the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to be related to Modifier Keys.
It turned out that `xmodmap -pm` showed a different configuration between the two Linux.

Fedora 22 (not working) showed

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        Mode_switch (0xcb)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c)
```

While Ubuntu (working) was returning

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  ISO_Level3_Shift (0x6c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

With the help of [this Archlinux Wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap#Reassigning_modifiers_to_keys_on_your_keyboard), I was able to create the following `~/.Xmodmap`.

```
! First we need clear the existing mods
clear mod1
clear mod3
clear mod5
! The Mode_switch needs to be bound to a key, in order to work
! In my layout this wasn't the case, so I needed to manually do this
keycode 203 = Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch
! Finally delcare the correct modifiers
add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
add mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift Mode_switch
```

This fixed my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> shortcuts in PyCharm, now they are recognized as expected.
`Settings` `>` `Keymap` `>` `Use national layouts for shortcuts` is off.

Note, I can still write special chars like `ŋ` in other editors and also in PyCharm as long as no shortcut is bound to it.